# Not able to save .mp4 video to camera roll

Tags: ios, video, mp4, alassetslibrary

I have am iOS DVR application where i record and save video in .mp4 format in the document directory. 
I am trying to move that video to camera roll but i am not able to move it. 
I think it might be because of video format. Below is format of the video
H264 - MPEG-4 AVC
Resolution: 352 x 258
Frame rate: 15

I tried UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum but no luck.

I also tried to convert the video to another .mp4 using asset library using following code but status is always Failed.

```
 [self convertVideoToLowQuailtyWithInputURL:localUrl outputURL:outputURL handler:^(AVAssetExportSession *exportSession)
{
    if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {
        // Video conversation completed
    }          
}];

- (void)convertVideoToLowQuailtyWithInputURL:(NSURL*)inputURL outputURL:(NSURL*)outputURL handler:(void (^)(AVAssetExportSession*))handler {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:outputURL error:nil];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void) {
         handler(exportSession);
     }];
}
```

How can I save recorded video file to camera roll ?

Comment: there's an [`.error` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetExportSession_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAssetExportSession/error) that you can access within the handler.  What error comes back when it fails?

Comment: It just gives: "The operation could not be completed" with code: -12894